# Export Excel from SQL Server - data type changes - why?

Tags: sql-server, excel, export-to-excel

In my project I'm exporting data from SQL Server to Excel using following code

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0 
Xml;HDR=NO;Database=D:\sathish\AA\GR_WITH_OUT_INVOICE;"IMEX=1";', SELECT * 
FROM [Sheet1$C1:R]')    SELECT OI_COMP,OI_MAJOUR_ACC,OI_SUB_ACC ,OI_DEPT
,OI_AIR_LINE,OI_AIR_TYPE,OI_AIR_MOD ,OI_CHANNEL,OI_PRO,OI_DIR_IND,OI_RES,
CASE WHEN CAST(OI_DEB AS NUMERIC(32,0)) = 0 THEN 00 ELSE CAST(OI_DEB AS NUMERIC(32,0)),
CASE WHEN CAST(OI_CRE AS NUMERIC(32,0)) 
= 0 THEN NULL ELSE CAST(OI_CRE AS NUMERIC(32,0)) END ,OI_DETAIL   ,OI_MSG,''''  
FROM ORCL_INTG_MACRO_GR_WITHOUT_INVOICE
ORDER BY  OI_PONO,CASE WHEN OI_COMP = 'Total' then '1' else '0' end,Case when oi_deb = 0 
then 0 else 1 end
```

In this `OI_CRE` and `OI_DEB` are numeric columns, but when exporting, they turn into strings. How can I export numeric to numeric in Excel?

I am using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: any advice ?. or Suggestion or anything am doing wrong in that query?\